# File transfer is slow in South Korea

Tags: windows-10, file-transfer, korean

I recently moved to South Korea and I noticed file transfer between an external hard drive and my laptop has slowed down tremendously. My backup/restore session usually takes less than 1 hour and now it takes 3 hours++. Is it something to do with the Internet? I thought South Korea has the fastest Internet in the world.

Comment: If its between your laptop and hard drive - its unlikely the internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you install any online banking software? South Korean banks require customers to install up to 4 security software to access their online banking website. Try uninstalling the software and test again.